# Angular UI router request URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular APP using UI Router.

```
.config(function($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('blog', {
            url: '/blog',
            templateUrl: 'assets/javascript/blog/blog.html',
            controller: 'BlogCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
});
```

If I press a link with `ui-sref="blog"`, the app load the blog view, but If I open in a new tab **myapp/blog**, it trows me 404 error.

Ps. I'm using HTML5 mode to remove the /#/

*Update:*

I have separate file for each route, in app.js I use

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

And have the `<base href="/">` in the `<head />`

I'm doing something wrong?
Can someone please explain?

Comment: can you show where you have used the html5 mode ?

Comment: update answer, check

Comment: have u specified the `base` url in your index.html page ?

Comment: @ViChU I need to specify my url like base href="http://my-url.com" /> ?

Comment: if your index.html is like this `www.url.com/index.html` use only `/` else if it is like `www.url.com/other/index.html` then use `/other/`

Answer (score 3):

For this to work on refresh/reload you need to properly set up a .htaccess file or similiar in your root and enable rewrite engine.

Something like this should work.

```
RewriteEngine On  
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```